# leverage browser caching in wordpress

Tags: cache, plugin-wp-supercache

I have added wp Super Cache, Auto optimize plugins on my website, But still, I am getting Leverage Browser Caching Issue how can I fix this in WordPress website

Comment: For which files is this still shown? Tools usually show this for external resources, such as Google Analytics, which you can't influence

Comment: For Leverage Browser Caching Issue use htaccess code. like :  https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html

Comment: HI, Patel Jignesh I have already gone through "vary". if I am adding those code into my htacesss file the complete website will not work.also in the Yoast plugin -> tools -> file editor there I can see an htaccess file which is already having those code.